# how to show highlight in :g command in vim

Tags: vim

Ideally I'd like to see some matching highlight when I do something like

```
:g/string_to_match/p
```

But it does not. Is there a way to make `string_to_match` highlighted?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. _When_ do you want the highlight to happen? While you type `string_to_match`? After typing the closing `/`? After typing `p`? After pressing Enter at the end? Please, clarify.

Comment: I meant after pressing Enter at the end, i.e. the whole command.

Comment: Oh, but so you want the highlight to happen in the window that you dismiss via `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, right?

Comment: To highlight search patterns (using `:g` or `/` etc.), you can `:set hlsearch`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Friedrich i have already had `hlsearch` on. When I don't use `:g` I can see the highlights. But I want the highlights to show up too while I am in the output of the `:g` command.

Comment: @Enlico, I want the highlight to happen inside the `:g` command's output, when I have long lines and it is very difficult to find where the matches are.

Comment: @QiangLi, is the answer to the question in my previous comment yes or no?

Comment: `you want the highlight to happen in the window that you dismiss via Press ENTER or type command to continue`, I don't see that window. After I apply the `:g` command and press enter, my window shows in the left bottom corner `-- More --`, if that is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

In your command:

```
:g/string_to_match/p
```

the part that is in charge of *printing* the matching lines *in the command-line* is the `p` at the end, short for `:help :print`, which can't be made to use highlighting.

Comment: Any chance the OP has `incsearch` off and just wants it on?

Comment: @Enlico you could ask them :-)

Comment: i am not seeing why it cannot be used highlighting `:[range]p[rint] {count} [flags]
                        Print {count} lines, starting with [range] (default
                        current line |cmdline-ranges|).
                        See |ex-flags| for [flags].`

Comment: It'll be nice to have highlighting, right? particularly when the lines are super long

Comment: You are not seeing why it can either. `:print` doesn't support highlighting, end of the story.

Comment: haha, interesting, but it would be such useful feature, is there a way to enable it?

Comment: It would have to exist for it to be enabled. If you know C, feel free to send a PR to vim/vim on GitHub.